# android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager and android.app.FragmentManager in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragmentmanager

guys.

I develop an app for Android API 14 and higher but I want to use `ViewPager` that comes in Android Support Library.

`ViewPager` needs `FragmentPagerAdapter` that uses `android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager` in the constructor. But within my activities I obviously have only `android.app.FragmentManager` because they extend `android.app.Activity` (not `android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity`).

Is there any way to convert `android.app.FragmentManager` to `android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager`?

Extend my activities from `FragmentActivity` is not an option for me.

Comment: delete the import and press ctrl+shift+o you will get it

Comment: Where will I get it from?

Comment: go to your activity and delete all the imports from your code and press ctrl+shift+o

Comment: @Nirmal, there's no problem in my imports. The problem is that android.app.Activity has no method getSupportFragmentManager() and I can't pass android.app.FragmentManager as a parameter to FragmentPagerAdapter's constructor.

Comment: yes exactly that things wont support its only support by fragment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use the v13 support library, which includes a ViewPager using a normal FragmentManager :)

Comment: Thank you! This is embarrassing. =)